# LaTeXTools: you need to migrate your preferences. See the README file for instructions

Tags: sublime-text

I was given the following error in sublime text during the build process:

```
LaTeXTools: you need to migrate your preferences. See the README file for instructions.
```

What do I need to do to fix it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

tldr: `In Sublime Text, open the command palette from the Tools menu, search for "LaTeXTools: Reconfigure and migrate settings," and hit Return.`

There was an update to the package [LaTeXTools](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools) as of 3-12-2014.  The preferences were restructured in the package, and likely you installed it via the `Command Palette Install Package`, which auto updates packages.  You will see in the readme, you just have to follow the directions copied from the site:

*Latest revision:* 2014-3-12.

*Highlight*: New, fully customizable build system! See below for a complete description. Note that, for now, things work more or less as before, but the infrastructure is there to customize things beyond your wildest dreams!

**NOTE**: due to the change in the build system, I had to overhaul the preferences settings. Please **read this** before proceeding any further:

- From now on, LaTeXTools will use a single settings file, called `LaTeXTools.sublime-settings`, which *must* exist in the `User` directory. By this I mean that LaTeXTools *will not work* until you have a proper `LaTeXTools.sublime-settings` file in the `User` directory.
- Because of this, LaTeXtools provides an easy way to create it, and even *automagically* migrate your settings from any old `LaTeXTools Preferences.sublime-settings` file you may have. In Sublime Text, open the command palette from the Tools menu, search for "LaTeXTools: Reconfigure and migrate settings," and hit Return. That's it! See the Settings section for other ways to migrate or reconfigure settings.
- The old settings file, `LaTeXTools Preferences.sublime-settings`, will no longer be honored.
- The `LaTeX.sublime-build` file is now for *internal use only*. Do *not* modify it! If you have a customized copy in `User`, delete it (but do *not* delete the original in the `LaTeXTools` directory). See the Settings section below for ways to *easily* customize the build command.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly, but I wonder where exactly is the `User` directory? Is it my personal user dir? In that case I don't see the indicated file ...

Comment: @Anh 'Your Hard Drive name'/Users/'Your User name aka home folder'/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text '2 or 3'/Packages/User/LaTeXTools.sublime-settings

Comment: Thanks! To be precise, for other Windows users, it's `/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 2/...` instead.

Answer (score 6):

Hi all (I'm the author of LaTeXTools),

a quick way to find the User directory is to select Browse Packages from the Preferences menu (on Windows---don't have a Mac handy to check). You will see one directory for each installed package, plus the User directory.

Answer (score -1):

`Preferences`->`package settings`->`LaTeXTools`->`Reconfigure LaTeXTools and migrate settings` in order to create the `LaTeXTools.sublime-settings`file.and migrate your preferences .

Just from my question ([How to modify the LaTeXTools.sublime-settings to make it work in Windows (MiKTEX)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176286/how-to-modify-the-latextools-sublime-settings-to-make-it-work-in-windows-miktex/176361#176361))