# How to modify the LaTeXTools.sublime-settings to make it work in Windows (MiKTEX)

Tags: miktex, sublime-text

First, I use Windows XP and MiKTeX.

As a thoroughly new-user of LaTeX, I don't know how to modify `LaTeXTools.sublime-settings` to make the ST3 comply the LaTeX code. Even after reading the introduction on https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools, I try to modify the file as follows:

Firstly, in the `platform_settings` section:

[image]

secondly,in the `builder_settings`:

[image]

but it still doesn't work!

And I know the `LaTeXTools.sublime-settings` itself has some explanations, but I can't understand it mainly because I'm not a geek or a coder. I don't dare to modify it.

Moreover,in any cases when I tap the `Ctrl+B`,the complying result is always like this:

[image]

even without the UTF-8 (actually I don't know anything about UTF-8,but I still install the ConvertToUTF8 package)

[image]

Comment: After `"miktex"` there shouldn't be a comma.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of the LaTeXTools plugin. Your output is very strange: when you type Ctrl-B, the plugin code isn't even run: what you are showing, for some reason, is the build output for python files!

I am afraid you may have a configuration issue with Sublime Text. Also, how did you install the plugin? Did you use Package Control? Finally, make sure that, when you open a tex file, the word "LaTeX" is displayed in the status bar (bottom part of the ST window), on the right.

Comment: Yes I make a mistake. may I give you a suggestion about the readme in GitHub ? the fifth paragragh in the `Requirements and Setup`section, you should explain in detail ,for example tell the user to tap `Preferences`->`package settings`->`LaTeXTools`->`Reconfigure LaTeXTools and migrate settings`  in order to create the `LaTeXTools.sublime-settings` file. Yes ,actually I didn't create the file and consequently fail.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I hope all is working now. BTW, the `Requirements and Setup` section does tell the user to generate the `LaTeXTools.sublime-settings` via the Command Palette (a standard Sublime Text feature)... But perhaps I should be even more explicit.

Comment: (*^__^*)maybe there are scarcely new users like me.BTW the process is indeed long and you omit some parts to some extent which makes me confused .

Comment: Sure, I understand. Thanks for the feedback!